# I need something similar to Selenium but much faster and that it does not require a webdriver (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping

is there a way i could control(move mouse, send input) without using selenium and NO browsers necessary. I need it to be fast, i saw some programs like have proxies and they basically control them and move mouse to specific locations, and go through google like that, is there a way i could do this? I need to solve a 1 click captcha ( it's just a click, nothing special ) but selenium is way too slow and i need something faster.

Comment: The point of Selenium is that its's a general tool which can be used to automate anything with a web interface. If you want to be able to automate your own tool, then of course, you're free to open up a socket / whatever and act on received data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a hacky way of automation with [PyAutoGUI](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui), a tool which automates mouse movement and keyboard inputs. I used this in combination with a regular Chrome browser to scrape a few pages. Although I suspect this will not be faster than Selenium. Alternatively you could try [requests-html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html).

Comment: Thanks for that, but what I need to do is solve a 1 click captcha that does not need any image selections or anything, and i cannot do this with requests, i need something that is ultimately fast and small CPU usage, however, i appreciate your suggestion